# C: Scanf string with field skipper "%*" applied on conversion specifier in while loop

Tags: c, scanf, conversion-specifier

I have defined a structure

```
typedef struct EMP {
    char name[100];
    int id;
    float salary;
} EMP;
```

and I use it in a while-loop for input

```
EMP emprecs[3];
int i;

i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
    printf("\nEnter Name: ");
    scanf("%*[\n\t ]%[^\n]s", emprecs[i].name);
    printf("\Enter Id: ");
    scanf("%d", &emprecs[i].id);
    printf("\nEnter Salary: ");
    scanf("%f", &emprecs[i].salary);
    i++;
}
```

but the loop only takes the first name and skips all other input after that (it finishes, but with empty input). This example is from a C textbook, so where is the problem?

It works somewhat better without the `"%*[\n\t ]"` field skip, but the textbook tells you to use it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this

```
scanf(" %*[\n\t ]%[^\n]s", emprecs[i].name);
      ^^^
     White space
```

instead of

```
scanf("%*[\n\t ]%[^\n]s", emprecs[i].name);
```

Also,

```
scanf(" %d", &emprecs[i].id);

scanf(" %f", &emprecs[i].salary);
```

Comment: `%d` and `%f` already skip whitespace. So the space behind it is superfluous. In fact, only `%c`, `%[` and `%n` are the format specifiers to which whitespace matters. And `%*[\n\t ]` is superfluous too after you've added before it.

Comment: I got it working by using the white space before % in all scanfs AND by removing the %*[\n\t ]. Thank you for the tip! I still don't understand why the field skip is not working the way the textbook said.